# Unifying theorem for the turning number and the Gauss-Bonnet theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, curves, surfaces, curvature

The statement that the turning number of a planar curve is a multiple of $2\pi$ and the Gauss-Bonnet theorem are similar in that they both state that the integral of a curvature measure depends on the topology but not the shape of the manifold. Is there a theorem that unifies the two statements that yields the former for $n=1$ and the latter for $n=2$? What does it say for $n=3$?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#Generalizations) link lists several generalizations of the GB theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unifying concept is the degree of the Gauss map of a closed hypersurface. In general, if you have a smooth mapping $f\colon X\to Y$ between compact oriented (Riemannian) $n$-manifolds, the integral of its Jacobian gives the degree of the map times the volume of $Y$. More precisely, if $\omega$ is the volume form of $Y$, then
$$\int_X f^*\omega = \text{deg}(f)\int_Y\omega.$$
For a detailed discussion, see $\S$9 of Chapter 4 of Guillemin & Pollack's *Differential Topology*.

Comment: Thank you, Ted, for a masterful response! Is there a more elementary way to describe what you said (even it it means loss of generality)? For instance, w/o differential forms. Also, to get Gaussian curvature, do we take f =  Gauss map?

Comment: You can define degree in many ways; you need either some algebraic topology or differential forms to prove the formula I stated. Noted that I stated it in terms of the Jacobian in the preceding sentence. Curvature, of course, is the Jacobian of the Gauss map.

Comment: Thanks again. Does the symbol $f^*$ represent the Jacobian of $f$? Also, would you happen to know who the original author of the formula is and if the formula has a name?

Comment: No, $f^*\omega$ is called by pullback of $\omega$ by $f$. I know no name attached to this formula, although it is Brouwer who first defined the degree of a mapping.

Comment: Could you illustrate how this theorem reduces to the classical Gauss-Bonnet theorem for n=2?

Comment: You need to use the Poincaré-Hopf Theorem to relate the degree of the Gauss map to the Euler characteristic. Why don't you look at the reference I gave in the first place?

Comment: The proverbial endless profusion of names and symbols is very time-consuming and effort-intensive to overcome for what seems like a basic relationship.

Comment: Advanced mathematics is not for free.

Comment: This need not be advanced math :)